# What is a typical Notability's file size?

Tags: ipad, applications, apple-pencil

I don’t think I can research from the vendor, and I want to plan if I choose to use this app.

What if the notes contains that 20-minutes lecture/audio clips - what is the size for each of these attachments?

Comment: This might better be asked on the support website of the App's creator.

Comment: Check r/notability there are a similar posts about this there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure but my whole Notability folder is less than 300Mb and it includes over 300 notes including pictures, pdfs, text books, etc.

Comment: @pcbillions53 Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers